can i show a grouping tablix item in the footer..?
my setup
can i inherit a grouping tablix item in a new tablix or in a textbox outside the first tablix table
in the footer..?
i want to show the signature items in the footer. but in footer grouping values isn't binding properly. How can i achieve this.i also add page break on per id. so my per page details different.. if i take another tablix table and make it group same id though it is not working showing properly.

Your question is unclear, show what you have now and what you expect the results to look like. Limit this to a single question too, if you have other questions, ask them separately.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
